# Maror and vinegar at the Seder?

Tags: halacha, passover, marror-bitter-herbs

May the horseradish used for maror be put in vinegar after grating it on Erev Yom Tov and still be used for the mitzvah?

My understanding is that it may not be done.

Is that the case? If so, how do you prevent the horseradish from becoming oxidized (brown) by the seder?

Comment: @Meir Zirkind Does this mean that the jars of horseradish sold in stores with vinegar really can't be used for the mitzvah at the seder?

Comment: andrewmh20: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27205/whats-the-best-way-to-dip-maror-into-charoset-if-youre-using-horseradish#comment63584_27205

Comment: http://www.vosizneias.com/126760/2013/03/21/new-york-halachic-analysis-the-not-so-bitter-truth-about-maror/

Comment: Don't grate it!  Cut it and take a bite like a man :)

Comment: https://youtu.be/STFsOewI2Hs?t=421 vinegar really does affect things quickly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can not be used because if it's in vinegar for longer than 24 hours it's considered cooked. And even less than that is not good since the surface is "cooked".

Buy [Mason Jars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason_jar) - they are airtight and excellent for this. Walmart/Target/etc sell them by the case and they are pretty cheap - about $1 per jar.

Comment: Vinegar [may even](http://www.vosizneias.com/126760/2013/03/21/new-york-halachic-analysis-the-not-so-bitter-truth-about-maror/) be considered "kavush" in under 24 hours if it is considered a "davar charif".

Comment: Mason jars may be excellent, but any fairly airtight container (e.g. a plastic bag with a seal) will do. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in air-tight container and keep in refridgerator.

Comment: +1, and we'll see if it works after the seder. :)

Comment: Well, it worked--I do think Ariel's answer is more complete though.

Comment: Ariel tried to give a complete answer, but he forgot that horseradish is a Davar Charriff (very sharp) and therefore Kevisha to be like cooking is Bechdai Reticha (opinions ranging anywhere between 6-18 minutes